# How to draw a trapezoid using a function

Tags: geometry, functions, coordinate-systems

I would like to draw a trapezoid using a function. What's the best way to do it?

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/15484/TextFig23-8.png

Comment: What parameters do you want? I have something that depends on the height and the lengths of the two bases.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician I would like the height to be 4.5 and the length 6. But I would like to know how the function looks like, the parameters aren't a problem.

Comment: That's just one length, no? You need the length of the bottom and the top for a trapezoid. In any case: $$\min\left(\max\left(0,\frac{h}{b-t}\left(b-2\left|x-\frac{b}{2}\right|\right)\right),h\right)$$